# How to generate a comma separated list of random ints

Tags: shell, numeric-data, random

I am trying to generate a comma separated **unordered** list of ints between 1 and 10, I have tried the following but it results in an ordered list:

```
seq -s "," 10 | shuf
```

Comment: Are you trying to emulate a deck of 10 cards or 10 trows of a dice (of 10 faces)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `paste -s` to join lines:

```
shuf -i1-10 | paste -sd, -
```

This uses `-i` option of shuf to specify a range of positive integers.

The output of `seq` can be piped to shuf:

```
seq 10 | shuf | paste -sd, -
```

Or `-e` to shuffle arguments:

```
shuf -e {1..10} | paste -sd, -
```

Answer (score 7):

There are two kinds of lists of numbers between 1 and 10. Which one do you need?

The best way to explain them is to use an analogy:

1. Put 10 balls numbered from 1 to 10 in a bag. In each turn extract one ball, read the number and do not return the ball to the bag. That generates a list of maximum 10 numbers. All numbers will appear in the list, but (by force) only once.

   Such a list would be generated by commands similar to:

   ```
   $ echo $(seq 10 | shuf) | tr " " ","
   10,7,5,2,3,9,1,4,8,6

   $ shuf -i1-10 | paste -sd, -
   1,9,4,6,2,8,10,5,3,7
   ```
2. Put 10 balls numbered from 1 to 10 in a bag. In each turn extract one ball of the bag, read the number on it and **return** the ball to the bag. The list may be infinite, numbers may take a while in repeating.

   Such a list could be generated with a command similar to:

   ```
   $ shuf -n 20 -r -i1-10 | paste -sd, -
   9,9,7,8,2,8,5,5,4,9,8,6,6,6,4,10,6,6,9,7
   ```

Answer (score 6):

`shuf` shuffles lines, if you only give it one line, there's not many possible results. Instead, give it lines and then change the newlines to commas afterwards:

```
$ seq 10 | shuf | tr '\n' ',' | sed '$s/,$/\n/'
1,7,8,2,9,4,6,3,5,10
```

(The last `sed` changes the very last comma to a newline. There might be better ways. Like using `paste` as in [@rowboat's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/643233/170373))